# Using Boost.Random to generate multiprecision integers from a seed

Tags: c++, boost, random, mersenne-twister, multiprecision

I am attempting to use the Boost multiprecision libraries for C++ to generate large random numbers. I have been unable to create a generator which is seeded by the time or another random number, so my generator produces the same numbers on every run. How do I seed the generator with a changing value to produce different values on each run? Here is the code which works but produces the same values on each run:

```
 using namespace boost::multiprecision;
 using namespace boost::random;

 typedef independent_bits_engine<mt19937, 512, mpz_int> generator_type;
 generator_type gen;

 std::cout << gen() << "\n\n";
```

I have seeded the std mersenne twister before with success:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 410);
std::cout << dis(gen);
```

but I am not sure how to seed the multiprecision mt.  I get an error if I try to attach any arguments to the generator_type declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be sure to include the right headers in the right order. Make sure `boost/multiprecision/random.hpp` is included **before** e.g. `boost/random.hpp`. <sup>[1]</sup>

Here's a working sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec5daeff6224691f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
    using Int = mp::mpz_int;

    boost::mt19937 rng(3); // fixing seed for demo
    boost::uniform_int<Int> gen(-pow(Int(2), 400), pow(Int(2), 400));

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << gen(rng) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
-1933652715378833784248363501979652496795524829874743132697181322648247480952527478485970668716806865063045317090084841622
-1468881213423638668843172777487968633185322950671475476288214928834762957270366851213470028408822700452414112732095789399
-438410269130756764874038685663894375462191729266787898021001121529040612201593866121171654735148672212107859934777249455
1640218057904403949431629353470797958943403389857715009204662011172706206212175540336638682612917363014646204359229208161
2080556950904231221688486212902649050443577133350992840521950777901511719409216800649680002332270542856870490906586634021
-2462847552934789794366130512379986584363897268428607239076390917679673552257507232435012961043902569359791960286013555735
1862125165202309929540318106374963238582997665808535945941185531430178511983671609033768595314282085775703389782906055681
-2252919975572088150601736662143078753669379374770846936106371833826830834376177961242332270710557376868189820866644291936
986998873018694187216384502983789929097242088320473495018118860428802373488463609060400540575932015408503979156759366945
111638721010166959954664901006097000984357549061159193446548907668369849648549091048841517202745565156043524728780018634
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For rationale see the header:

```
namespace boost{ namespace random{ namespace detail{
//
// This is a horrible hack: this declaration has to appear before the definition of
// uniform_int_distribution, otherwise it won't be used...
// Need to find a better solution, like make Boost.Random safe to use with
// UDT's and depricate/remove this header altogether.
//
template<class Engine, class Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates>
boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates> 
   generate_uniform_int(Engine& eng, const boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& min_value, const boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& max_value);

}}}
```

Comment: Boost version 1.60 deprecates the header boost/multiprecision/random.hpp

Answer (score -1):

You can seed an `independent_bits_engine` in the following way:

```
gen.seed(a_value_used_as_seed)
```

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/independent_bits_engine/seed/).

**EDIT**

The `mt19937` produces `uint32_t` integers and uses the same type as seed. However, it accepts also a seed sequence, wich can be used to create seeds that are beter distributed across the entire 32-bit range. The seed sequence can be any class, as long as it defines some functions. One of them is the following:

```
void generate(type*,type*)
```

These two different ways of seeding are represented by two template functions.

The type that is used in the `independent_bits_engine` is the `mpz_int` integer. When the engine is seeded, it passes the seed to the base engine, the mersenne twister. For the `mt19937` the `mpz_int`, is not its base type, so the compiler selects the second template function and interprets the seed as a seed sequence. This causes an error because the `mpz_int` class, doesn't have a `generator`function.

Comment: Thank you, @Vincent. I am trying my best to apply this syntax to the boost::random version, but with no success. The code works well with the std independent_bits_engine, but of course can't generate numbers beyond 64 bits. Any variation of similar syntax I attempt with Boost::Random gives the compile-time error: error: no
      member named 'generate' in
      'boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int,
      1>'